# SQL CASE statement with table and operator

Tags: sql-server, switch-statement, case

trying to apply operator on the basis on condition.

I want to make below query work;

```
SELECT fName,
       LName
WHERE active =1
  AND CASE @statusid
           WHEN -100 THEN (StatusID NOT IN (-5,-3))
           WHEN -101 THEN StatusID NOT IN (-5, -3, -1)
           WHEN -102 THEN StatusID NOT IN (-3)
           ELSE StatusID = @statusid
      END
```

Comment: what error are you getting for this query?

Comment: T-SQL only supports `CASE` **expression**. T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements.

Answer (score 3):

As I mention in my comment, T-SQL does not support `Case` (`Switch`) statements, only `CASE` expressions. What you need to do here, however, is just use plain "old" boolean logic:

```sql
SELECT fName,
       lName
--Where is your FROM?
--I have added one
FROM dbo.YourTable
WHERE active = 1
  AND ((@statusid = -100 AND StatusID NOT IN (-5,-3))
   OR  (@statusid = -101 AND StatusID NOT IN (-5,-3,-1))
   OR  (@statusid = -102 AND StatusID != -3)
   OR  StatusID = @Statusid);
```

Comment: Thanks Larnu for sharing the solution

Comment: If it solves the problem, please consider marking it as the solution, @Vikrant, so that future readers know it was helpful.